# cannot destroy a database using rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and while practising the tutorials I got the following error. Any ideas..

```
$ rake destroy scaffold Microposts --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'destroy'
/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'

/home/keval/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trey `rails destroy scaffold Microposts`